# error connecting to open vpn from my server

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

i'm connecting to an open vpn server but i dont know why i does not connect.

i use this commend:

```
sudo openvpn ./config.ovpn
```

here is the output:

```
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=434468 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=435631 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=438493 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1450 EF:123 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=438770 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=438799 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1559,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=438896 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]176.123.64.49:1194
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=440331 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
Sun Jan 21 11:11:10 2024 us=440389 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]176.123.64.49:1194 [nonblock]
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=441041 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]176.123.64.49:1194
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=441112 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=441129 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]176.123.64.49:1194
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=441946 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]176.123.64.49:1194, sid=2d017c36 80a1daa2
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701041 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=IR, ST=FARS, L=SHZ, O=SUMS, OU=SUMS, CN=CA
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701630 VERIFY KU OK
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701671 Validating certificate extended key usage
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701692 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701707 VERIFY EKU OK
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=701721 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=IR, ST=FARS, L=SHZ, O=SUMS, OU=SUMS, CN=172.16.16.73
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=848427 Connection reset, restarting [0]
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=848814 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=848954 SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=849716 Restart pause, 40 second(s)
```

which repeats over time.

can anybodey help what is the problem.
also here is the config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote ovpn.sums.ac.ir
port 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-client
remote-cert-tls server
verb 4
mute 10
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA1
auth-user-pass
auth-nocache
redirect-gateway def1
route-nopull
route route-nopull
route 172.16.0.49 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Sun Jan 21 11:11:11 2024 us=848427 Connection reset, restarting [0]

Someone sent a RST.

Iran routinely blocks things they don't like, and probably kills VPN tunnels on sight.